# Error "The method 'collection' isn't defined for the type 'CollectionReference'" in Cloud Firestore 4.14 (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm encountering an error when trying to access a subcollection in Cloud Firestore using Flutter. Here's the relevant code

```
Future<List> getcollectioncategory() async {
  // Get the main collection
  CollectionReference collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("expenses");
  CollectionReference subcoleecion = collectionReference.collection("enero-app-gastos"); // Error line

  // Get the data from the collection
  QuerySnapshot collectionSnapshot = await subcoleecion.get();

  var day;
  if (collectionSnapshot.docs.length != 0) {
    for (var doc in collectionSnapshot.docs) {
      print(doc.data());
      hola.add(doc.data());
      day = hola[0];
    }
  } else {
    print("bad query");
  }
  return hola;
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting this code to do?  Collections don't contain other collections.  Collections contain documents, and those documents can have other nested collection under them.  There must be a document between each nested collection, and you must know that document ID in order to build a collection reference to its nested collections.

Answer (score 1):

cause of this problem is that the code is trying to access a subcollection directly from the collectionReference object but the collection method is used to retrieve a subcollection within a document, not a subcollection within a collection.

give a try to following

i used *subcollection name in place of your *subcoleecion so that it will makes easy/obvious to others.

```
Future<List> getCollectionCategory() async {
  // Get the main collection
  CollectionReference collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("expenses");
  DocumentReference documentReference = collectionReference.doc("documentId"); // Replace "documentId" with the actual document ID

  // Get the subcollection
  CollectionReference subcollection = documentReference.collection("enero-app-gastos");

  // Get the data from the subcollection
  QuerySnapshot subcollectionSnapshot = await subcollection.get();

  var hola = [];
  if (subcollectionSnapshot.docs.length != 0) {
    for (var doc in subcollectionSnapshot.docs) {
      print(doc.data());
      hola.add(doc.data());
    }
  } else {
    print("bad query");
  }
  return hola;
}
```